# Error in running a python script-In pip installation

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am running a python script where it is setting up an environment in unix to run other python scripts. It is trying to install pip and it fails with the following error.

```
   2016-01-25 12:05:50,291 - Checking if pip is installed.

   2016-01-25 12:05:50,291 - Pip is not currently installed.
   2016-01-25 12:05:50,291 - Installing pip.
     Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/tmpoDUDVr.py", line 19017, in <module>
     main()
     File "/tmp/tmpoDUDVr.py", line 194, in main
  bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
    File "/tmp/tmpoDUDVr.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
      File "/tmp/tmpm4FmfJ/pip.zip/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>

       File "/tmp/tmpm4FmfJ/pip.zip/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>

        File "/tmp/tmpm4FmfJ/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 29, in <module>

       File "/tmp/tmpm4FmfJ/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 39, in <module>

      File "/tmp/tmpm4FmfJ/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 14, in <module>

       File "/tmp/tmpm4FmfJ/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 31, in   <module>

         ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSHandler

Failed to install pip. Error was Command '['python', '/tmp/tmpoDUDVr.py', '-    -user', '--upgrade', '--force-reinstall']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I have already installed pip using the command yum -y install python-pip but still it throws this error. I am not able to find this tmp/tmpoDUDVr.py file and everytime I run this tmp file varies.I tried searching hidden files too(ls -a) Could you please shed light? Any thoughts much appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "sudo" in this case. PIP was installed the first time as root...

Comment: Yes I tried installing as sudo too. (sudo yum install python-pip) , Still same error.